# Identity: After "force"-account-login(without providing password), normal logging in way(with password) stops working

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

So,

I'm logging into an account using

`await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);`

It allows me to login without password - basically Force.

then after a while I'm going to login form, filling login/password fields, sending POST and logging via this code:

`var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(input.UserName, input.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);`

It evaluates as a `true`

but for some reason I'm still unauthorized.

I figured out that when I remove this cookie:

[image]

Then everything works properly.

So, I wanted to perform a "hack" and while returning LoginFormView I added that to controller's method

```
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    if (cookie == "MyApp")
    {
        Response.Cookies.Delete("MyApp");
        Response.Cookies.Append("MyApp", "", new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = true, Expires = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)) });
    }
}
```

But it doesn't really solve my issue.

That's my cookie config

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login";
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyApp";
    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600);
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Anybody has an idea how to make it work?

Comment: `_signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true)` does not log you in without a password. The first argument is an `ApplicationUser` object which includes a password. Also, `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` returns a task `Task<SignInResult>`, which has several boolean properties on it. Which of those properties are you referring to when you say "it evaluates as true"? Your question is a bit hard to follow. Assuming that you go to the login form within minutes of calling `_signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true)`, I have to wonder what happened to your auth cookie?

Comment: "for some reason I'm still unauthorized", What made you conclude that? Did you call any other action after logging in. Are the `Authorize` attributes placed correctly?

Comment: @JordanWilcken Weird. I'm just performimg ``context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == Username``) and then SignInAsync(user, true) and I'm logged in on that account.  ``Which of those properties are you referring to when you say "it evaluates as true"?`` ``result.Succeeded``

Comment: @Joelty The short answer is that you shouldn't be doing any manual cookie management. That's the kind of thing you want the framework to do for you. I just don't know enough about your project to point the way. You might try simplifying things. Try deleting that code where you configure the application cookie. Stop doing an initial login with the first user that comes out of your context (which is a strange thing to be doing in any case). Simplify until it works.